# PostgreSQL - How to match a value in a table where column has values with comma separation

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the following field values:

[image]

I want to do a `select` where I can match a value from this keyword column. For example:

```
SELECT templateid FROM public.templates WHERE keyword='Yes'
```

I don't want to use `LIKE` because in the case one of the comma-separated values is `Yessy` then I will get a return and that's not correct.

It has to be an exact match of one of the comma separated values.

Any clue?

Comment: That's a horrible database design. Do you have a chance to fix this before you continue?

Comment: yes I can change that, what do you recommend me? Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string into an array:

```
SELECT templateid 
FROM public.templates 
WHERE 'Yes' = any(string_to_array(keyword, ','))
```